# Creating tag-like feature in Django

Tags: python, django, tags, categories

I'm new to Django and trying to figure out the code to create URLs for categories for my objects. The way Its working now I have a URL for each category but I'm trying to make a shortcut so if I create more categories I don't have to add another URL to URLs.py.

The Model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    FOOTWEAR = "Footwear"
    CLOTHING = "Clothing"
    OUTERWEAR = "Outerwear"
    ITEM_CATEGORY_CHOICE = (
        (FOOTWEAR, 'Footwear'),
        (CLOTHING, 'Clothing'),
        (OUTERWEAR, 'Outerwear'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(
                   max_length=20,
                   choices=ITEM_CATEGORY_CHOICE,
                   null=True,)
```

Before I had a url for each category. I was able to set up the URL for specific category:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$',
        'collection.views.specific_category',
        name="specific_category"),
```

In views is where I have the issue. I'm not sure what i'm suppost to be pointing to in the views:

```
def specific_category(request, category):
    if category:
        sneakers = Sneaker.objects.filter(category = "__").order_by('-date')

    else:
        sneakers = Sneaker.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

Right now with the code as is the page opens up blank. I feel like the answer is right in my face and i can't see it. Is my model wrong? Pointing me to any resources that explain would also be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't return anything for your view code, how is it going to work?

Comment: I know this. But returning "footwear" in views will return footwear no matter what I use as the category in the URL. How do I return all categories in views so whatever category I manually type in URL shows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to do with your view method then.

Comment: your view must return the content (actually, full http response, not only content), it doesn't point anywhere. If you don't return content, you get empty page.

Comment: I guess that's my question. How can I point the return to all the categories? So if i want to type "__/categories/clothing" manually the site will return all items with the clothing category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create an html file which looks for a generic context variable, for example:

category_items.html

```
Category:
{{ category }}

Items:
{{ for item in items }}
    {{ item.name }}
{{ endfor }}
```

That way, no matter what you filter in your views, you can still display the results using the same html page. Also, change `category = '__'` to `category=category`, so it will capture the category name from the url.

views.py

```
def specific_category(request, category):
    if category:
        sneakers = Sneaker.objects.filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

    else:
        sneakers = Sneaker.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    return render(request, 'category_items.html', {'category': category, 'items': sneakers})
```